# How to recreate bad character encoding? Portuguese characters issue

Tags: python, character-encoding

I have files with badly encoded Portuguese and Spanish characters, i.e. "Ol**Ã¡** amigo" instead of "Ol**á** amigo".
I don't know these languages and it is hard to find all such misplacements by hand.

My idea is to recreate such bad encodings for each special character, so that I can automatically replace it in all the files.

I tried doing it like

```py
b"á"
```

or to write such character to a file and then read it as:

```py
with open("file.txt", encoding="ascii") as f:
   f.read()
```

but every attempt raised an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I solved it minutes after posting...
Anyway, for others struggling with it is all here: https://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html